Update custom field individual checkbox value without overwriting the other values in the set

CiviCRM 5.78.3
CiviRules 3.14.0
When using the "Set Custom Field on contact" action to update a custom field that contains a set of checkboxes, is it possible to update an individual checkbox without overwriting all the other values in the set?
The help text states that "Complex values can be set using JSON expressions" and I'm wondering if this is the answer. However, I cannot find any information about how to correctly format the JSON expression.
Any help greatly appreciated.
